# How do you use SetAlert with the Node.js Alex Skill SDK?

Tags: node.js, alexa-skills-kit

I am a ASK n00b and I want to create a skill, that when activated will send messages to the user on a schedule. Later I want to pause/resume that schedule. I am currently hacking the Node.js fact example to learn the ropes, but could use some veteran knowledge and help.

Examples are the preferable response.

Answer (score 0):

Sending messages "on a schedule" is currently not supported by ASK.
This feature has been announced but there is no access yet.

https://www.engadget.com/2017/05/16/amazon-echo-push-notifications/